# Google App Engine Query .addFilter

Tags: java, google-app-engine, add-filter

I've been struggling with queries with Google's datastore and wanted to get some help.

I have a form that saves a double to the datastore. Here is a snippet from the servlet:

```
String temp = req.getParameter("temp");
message.setProperty("temp", temp);
```

`temp` is a string but containes a number with decimal places.

In my JSP code I'm trying to run the query:

```
query.addFilter("temp",Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, -0.9);
```

But it only seems to work if the value (-0.9) is an integer (-1).  Also, when I try to use a variable I get an invalid constant error:

```
query.addFilter("temp",Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, request.getParameter('mintemp'));
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chance are you are setting your property as a String, you should store the property as a Float instead see the documentation for [setProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Convert your String to a Float before setting the Entity property:

```
message.setProperty("temp", Float.parseFloat(temp));
```